# Completely bizarre Firefox CSS bug

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I've been doing front end development for a long time, and I have NEVER come across a bug like this before...

Save the following HTML to a file and view it in Firefox (mine is 3.6.3):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;}
    h2 {font-weight: normal;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <h2>Some normal text <strong>some bold text</strong> weird huh?</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to give it a shot the output is like your cat walked across your keyboard while character map was turned on, except in the `strong` tags.

I feel like this may be a font issue? When I get rid of `font-weight: normal` it goes back to normal, but I don't want everything to be bolded in my `h2`... Anyone have any ideas? More importantly, is anyone able to reproduce this??

Thanks.

### EDIT

Here's a [screenshot](http://a.yfrog.com/img362/6880/wtff.png). It works fine in all other browsers, and all text that has not previously been set as bold (normal text) renders fine.

Comment: Renders exactly as expected in my copy of Firefox 3.5.9, perhaps a screenshot is in order?  I suspect the problem is with your browser or OS; the code is too simple to be some kind of long-standing rendering bug with Firefox.

Comment: Looks ok to me in FF 3.6.3/win

Are you sure your font is OK?

Comment: Looks fine to me in Firefox 3.6.3. Could you be more specific about the nature of the problem? A screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: [It works on my machine](http://jsbin.com/ulezo/).

Comment: Perfectly fine to me, FFX 3.6.3 and Windows 7.

Comment: Looks fine to me FF 3.6.3/Ubuntu 9.10. Screenshot?

Comment: Here's a screenshot, guys: http://a.yfrog.com/img362/6880/wtff.png

Comment: *View > Character Encoding* tell us what's been selected there.

Comment: This is something Helvetica specific, IIRC there's a bug report for it, hang on.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked your encoding?

When you remove `Helvetica` or `Sans-Serif` and replace them with other fonts, do you have the same problem? For example, have you tried using another fonts and then combinations of `Helvetica` and `Sans-Serif` with those:

`Courier`, `Helvetica`

`Courier`, `Sans-Serif`

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be something Helvetica specific. Here is a number of reports with screenshots that look exactly like your case.

- [Mozilla Bug #444203 -  Helvetica font rendering garbled/garbage on some web sites](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444203)
- [Mozilla Forum - Firefox 3 displays garbage characters](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?forumId=1&comments_parentId=89178)

They mention workarounds. On server side:

> - if the CSS definition defines the font family using font: instead of
>     font-family:, this bug does not occur.
> - when setting the font-family by way of font-family: (instead of by font:),
>     the error only occurs once you're showing fonts over 20pixels in size. It
>     doesn't matter if the font size is set by way of em or px, but once the actual
>     display size is over 20px, it gets garbled.

On the client side, it seems to be recommended to remove or re-install the Helvetica font. Can you check your fonts folder for any `HELVETIC.TTF` or similar files?

Comment: i tried the `font:` setting in my CSS... still garbled. i don't even have a HELVETIC.TTF in my fonts folder

Comment: @Jason Really strange. You definitely have *no* Helvetica in the fonts folder, neither TTF nor OpenType nor Type1?

Comment: i have some helvetica neue fonts... where to i get a helvetica font? everywhere i look it's like $30... shouldn't it be on my machine already?!

Answer (score 2):

This is may be due to a strange version of Helvetica loaded on your machine. Try disabling that font locally and see what happens.

Comment: weird... i don't even have "helvetica" in my comp... wtf

Comment: OK. Maybe it is the reference to "Sans-Serif" then. I believe it should be "sans-serif" (no caps).

Comment: Also, try checking to see what your browser has set for the default "sans-serif" font. It may be that font is screwy.

Comment: What do you have set for your default font? Check Tools > Options > Content in Firefox.

Comment: Hmm. Continuing along these lines - what is your default font for the "sans-serif" style? Then try resetting that font to some font that you know is not corrupted. To change the default "sans-serif" font, Tools > Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is something to do with the encoding (and not font).
Check your encoding as it is decided by firefox: View -> Character Encoding.
Is it UTF-8?
Does changing it to anything else (say Western (ISO8859-1)) change the characters?

Can you try disabling your addons, especially the theme and check (start firefox in safe mode)? Perhaps some add on is meddling with the encodings...