# Special Characters in 20px+ Screw up in Firefox 3.6

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

Hey everyone, I'm working on a site and any special characters ("&rsquo;" "&hellip;") turn into garbage at any font size over 19px. I'm using fonts I defined with @font-face, and the garbage disappears when I use a fallback font. This is Firefox 3.6.13.

I've tried defining the fonts in the page with a font: declaration rather than a font-family: declaration ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650038/completely-bizarre-firefox-css-bug)) but it doesn't work.

I **can** use the standard straight quote and skip the special characters, but have you *seen* a straight quote in a heading at 40px? Ugh.

Anybody seen this bug, and any suggestions to fix it server-side?

Comment: Is it possibly a problem with the embedded font?

Comment: Which entity codes are you using? have you tried using the unicode point instead of the common name (ie. `&#8220;` instead of `&ldquo;`)?

Comment: @Craig : Oddly it will reproduce for two embedded fonts in the same family, but doesn't for a third from a different family. The odd thing is that the two broken fonts are Fontin and Fontin small caps, full font-families, and the working one is Zebra-regular, which has only the basics. You might be right - but the problem DOES NOT reproduce on IE or Chrome ( or Firefox on linux).

Comment: @prodigitalson Tried those :/ Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I (sort of) figured out what's going on. Firefox 3+ will automatically "optimizeLegibility" for any fonts over 20px (look up CSS "text-rendering" property).

For whatever reason, the fonts I am using don't render correctly when Firefox applies this value. If I specifically declare:

```
body { text-rendering: optimizeSpeed; }
```

Suddenly the problem disappears. Obviously this might bother someone who likes the effect of "optimizeLegibility" (it's definitely a nice effect), but if you can't change font-faces and you're getting garbage in your headings, I hope this helps.

Comment: I would suggest that you accept this answer (little check under answer score) if you are not looking for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will simply have to use another font?